# Does Corda node support the concept of an organization and users in the organization?

Tags: corda

Does Corda node support the concept of an organization and users in the organization? The ORG user must have visibility to transactions of the node. And is it possible to add users within this Organization who can be part of selected transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with Corda. I see two ways:

1. Use the Account library. Accounts are "logical" entities, i.e. subset of the node's vault. An ORG can be the Corda node and the users can be accounts owned by the node, which has complete visibility of the transactions. You can add as many accounts as you want. Note that an account only has public keys, the private keys are owned by the Corda node owner of the accounts. The flows are effectively ran by the Corda node, not by the Account themselves who are just effectively states that only have a name and a set of public keys (but not a X.509 identity, so they are not registered to the network. Only the Corda node is). A typical use case of this is a Group Company X (i.e the Corda node) who owns some Subsidiary Companies (its accounts). More info: https://training.corda.net/libraries/accounts-lib/ and https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md
2. Use the Business Network Membership: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/business-network-membership.html. In this case you have different Corda nodes connected to the same network, and a subset of these node share a "logical" network, which is made at application level in which you can set the roles and memberships. In pratice, this is a cordapp shared between them where there are states that identify an organization and its rules.

These two above are ways to effectively create "organizations". In Corda then you also have the Observer parties, who are parties that just want to be notified of some transactions without effectively be part of them.

Comment: In this case, how can we ensure the keys of the Account are safe (node owner does not hamper the keys/misuse the keys?) As the accounts could be a user within the origanization or could be a partner of the organization?

Comment: Accounts have only public keys. The private keys are owned by the node. Accounts in Corda are only abstractions at application level, they cannot run any flow, they are ran effectively by the node owner of the accounts. So, it depends on what you need. Maybe for your case the 2. would fit better.

Comment: "Accounts have only public keys" - I didnt quite get this. Is it not a key pair?

Comment: Yes, but the private key is held by the corda node. Accounts are AnonymousParty: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-identity.html and https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md#common-questions

Comment: From the above link - "To transact with an account, you must request that the node hosting the account generate a new key pair for the account."
so its a key pair. 

"Accounts are AnonymousParty with a public key generated from the private key of the node" - could not understand this. How do you generate a public key from an existing private key? Or are you referring to signing?

Comment: It's a new key pair (one or many) associated with the account in the Corda node.